# Constraining find_each

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a select statement,

```
SELECT `metrics`.* 
FROM `metrics` 
WHERE `metrics`.`engine` = 0 
  AND (`metrics`.connection_id = 27874) 
  AND (`metrics`.`id` > 181586235) 
ORDER BY `metrics`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1000
```

which is generated by `find_each` being called on a relation (e.g. `metric.engines.find_each`).  This select statement scans 15 million records each time it is run.

I'd like to make this lighter on the database by telling the query only to look for a range of `metrics.id`s (e.g. `metrics.id > 1 AND metrics.id < 1000`).

Is there a way to do this with `find_each`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find_each` can be applied to scopes like all finder methods:

```
Metric.where("metrics.id between 1 and 1000"]).find_each { ... }
```

EDIT: If you need to process all records but don't want to load them all at once, you can use the [find_in_batches](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_in_batches) method:

```
Metric.find_in_batches do |batch|
  batch.each { ... }
end
```